# App opens as "background process". Is it possible in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, background-process

I want to run an app as a background process. When click on the app icon then it doesn't show any view just start a background process.

Comment: Definitely not supported under iOS using React Native or any other framework.

Comment: Is it possible in Android? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS it's not possible, but for android, react native has [headlessJS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) that can be used to run a task when your app on the background.

The scenario should be like:

1. Register the headless js, and run it.
2. Then close the android app using `BackHandler.exitApp()`. More [reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html#exitapp)